# I passed product name in onclick() function using jquery? but error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
output += '<td class="cart-product-edit"><a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="SaveCart(' + element.CardID + ',' + element.ProductName + ')" class="product-edit"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></td>';

function SaveCart(cartid) {
  var URL = "<?php echo site_url();?>";
  var userid = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('userid');?>"
  var data = {
    userid: userid
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: URL + 'cart/SaveCart/' + cartid,
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {}
  });
}
```

Error:(console)   (bag is productname)

> cart:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: bag is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (cart:1)

Comment: will you include your html code? There must be something wrong with how you bind the event

Comment: function SaveCart($cartid)

Comment: sesion_data = $this->session->userdata('sessiondata');
$user_id = $session_data['user_id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.  The first is with this line:

```
onclick="SaveCart(' + element.CardID + ',' + element.ProductName + ')"
```

Your `element.ProductName` is presumably a string (named, in this case `Bag`) and that is causing your error.

You need to surround the string elements of your `onclick` with quotes:

```
onclick="SaveCart(' + element.CardID + ', \'' + element.ProductName + '\')"
```

The second issue is that `SaveCart` is defined with only a single parameter:

```
function SaveCart(cartid) {
```

You are actually passing two parameters to it, the `CardID` and the `ProductName`.

Maybe you don't need to pass the product name at all, in which case your `onclick` becomes:

```
onclick="SaveCart(' + element.CardID + ')"
```

Or you need to add the second parameter to `SaveCart`:

```
function SaveCart(cartid, productName) {
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it appears that the issue is because `element.CardID` and `element.ProductName` are strings, yet you have not wrapped them in quotes in the HTML output. You need to escape the quotes you wrap them in so that they don't break the syntax:

```
output += '<td ... onclick="SaveCart(\'' + element.CardID + '\',\'' + element.ProductName + '\')" ... </td>';
```

You also need to amend `SaveCart` to accept both arguments:

```
function SaveCart(cartid, productname) {
  // your logic here...
}
```

However a much better approach would be to get rid of the outdated `on*` event attributes and to attach your events unobtrusively. Then you can use `data` attributes to store the metadata in the element. Given you're already using jQuery, it can be done like this:

```js
var element = {
  CardID: 'abc123',
  ProductName: 'Lorem ipsum'
}

let output = `<td class="cart-product-edit"><a href="#" data-cardid="${element.CardID}" data-productname="${element.ProductName}" class="product-edit"><i class="fa fa-plus">Click me</i></a></td>`;
$('table tr').append(output);

$('table').on('click', '.product-edit', function() {
  let $a = $(this);
  let cardId = $a.data('cardid');
  let productName = $a.data('productname');
  
  console.log(cardId, productName);
  
  // send your AJAX here...
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr></tr></table>
```